# Combining case changing and substring variable expansion

Tags: string, bash, substr

If you append `^` to a variable, Bash capitalises the first letter of its contents. (Similarly, `,` sends it to lowercase and doubling-up either of these applies the transformation to the whole string, rather than just the first letter.)

```
foo="hello world"
echo ${foo^}  # Hello world
```

You can also do `${variable:position:length}` to extract a substring:

```
echo ${foo:0:1}  # h
```

So far, I haven't found a way to combine these without, obviously, creating a temporary variable. Is there a form where I can get just the capitalised first letter out of an arbitrary string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Parameter expansion operators do not compose, so if you want more than one side effect, you need a temporary variable (which can include overwriting the original value as shown by @fred) or an external tool to process the result of the expansion (as shown by @anubhava).

Your other alternative is to use a different shell that *does* support more complicated operations, like `zsh`:

```
% foo="hello world"
% % print ${(U)${foo:0:1}}
H
```

Answer (score 2):

It does not change the basic limitation you are seeing in terms of not being able to "chain" expansions, but you can assign the result of an expansion to the same variable and do away with the temporary variable.

For instance:

```
A=text
A="${A^}"
A="${A//x/s}"
echo "$A"
```

echoes "Test".

Answer (score 1):

You can use `tr` with substring:

```
tr [[:lower:]] [[:upper:]] <<< "${foo:0:1}"
H
```